# Is there a MATLAB function for reshaping array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to reshape two array. For example:

```
a=[17 21 24 32]
b=[10 15 18]
```

Thus, I want to get a new array:

```
c=[10 15 17 18 21 24 32]
```

How do it?
Thank you!

Comment: you mean `c=[a b]`. You want to concatenate them `cat()`

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply! I want to achieve that the new array is from small to big.

Comment: have you use your search engine to look for that?  "array is from small to big matlab" try that

Comment: Now I got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB command you need to arrange the elements is [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

```
>> c = sort([a,b])
c =
    10    15    17    18    21    24    32
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can do concatenation or union of arrays based on their length

```
if length(b)<length(a)
    c = [b,a];
else
    c = [a,b];
```

More about union https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.union.html